# Cannot create custom TestEnvironment in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I am trying to create a custom test environment with Jest as described in their official [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string)
Unfortunately I get the following error:

> Determining test suites to run...
> FAIL  acceptancetests/mongo.test.js
> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> TypeError: TestEnvironment is not a constructor
>
> ```
> at ../node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:88:25
> ```

My test is completely empty and my CustomTestEnvironment just calls the super classes. I am on the latest Jest version (24.3.1)

I think it is very weird, that the error is thrown within the Jest library.

This is my test-environment.js:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, this is a silly problem and I found the solution.

I had to export the `CustomEnvironment`

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  ...
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment
```

And also add it in the jest.config.js

```
const { defaults } = require("jest-config");
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: './../CustomEnvironment.js',
};
```

I don't know why the guide doesn't include that line :(

Comment: I have the same problem, but I do export. What does your config file look like?

Comment: Found it: you have to set the path to the file exporting the class in jest.config.js at ``testEnvironment``

Comment: I also had an issue with the file naming conventions.  If you don't include a relative directory in part of the path such as `--test-environment env.js` it will assume you're trying to import something from `node_modules`.  The proper way to import a file would be to say  `--test-environment ./env.js`

Comment: I found that in my `jest.config.js` I had to do this:

`testEnvironment: '<rootDir>/../jest/environment.js',`

Where my `rootDir` was `src` off of the project root.

Comment: `Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null`. What I've done wrong?

Comment: @testing_22 answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124222/7761396