# Jest: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I've setup a jest.env.js file - which I add to the jest.config.js `testEnvironment: './jest.env.js'` - to handle `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder`. But with my configuration I do get this error in my tests (jest@28):

```
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

>  7 | module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
     |                                                      ^
   8 |   async setup() {
   9 |     await super.setup()
  10 |     if (typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
```

I would like to understand the error itself and of course I would like to know how to fix it

My test would work, if I add

```
global.TextEncoder = require('util').TextEncoder
global.TextDecoder = require('util').TextDecoder
```

at the beginning of my testfile instead of using `testEnvironment`.

**jest.env.js**

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node')

module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup()
    if (typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
      const { TextEncoder } = require('util')
      this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder
    }
    if (typeof this.global.TextDecoder === 'undefined') {
      const { TextDecoder } = require('util')
      this.global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this error? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @obaqueiro I just use `import { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } from 'util';
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;`

Answer (score 0):

You must import `TestEnvironment` like this:

`const NodeEnvironment = require("jest-environment-node").TestEnvironment;`

[Mentionned here in the doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)